# Are unused local variables freed after inner function call?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm writing an application where data can be pre-processed and written to file. The data can then be loaded again to save re-computing on future runs, but needs to be modified to a common format before further processing.

Without pre-processed data, the program looks like:

```
void no_preprocess(std::vector<T>& a)
{
    std::vector<P> b = hard_work(a);
    magic(a, b);
}
```

and with the pre-processed data:

```
void foo(std::vector<T>& a, std::string path)
{
    std::vector<D> c = read(path);
    std::vector<P> b = easy_work(a, c);
    // Is c now free?
    magic(a, b);
}
```

Once `easy_work` has finished, `c` is never used again. What will happen to `c` once `magic` is called, i.e. are compilers clever enough free `c`?

Comment: `c` isn't even used by `easy_work()`. It is not used after it is declared.

Comment: Yes, since all C++ implementations have a [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). BTW you should use [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)

Comment: @cdhowie Oh dear, I've corrected the question!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Are you referring to using `std::move`?

Comment: No, but to the many new features of C++11; notably `auto` and λ (and functional programming style).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Then, what features are you referring to that might help me in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object will be destructed immediately when exiting the scope in which it is declared, and not a moment before.

The compiler cannot destruct locals at the point where they become "no longer used" because they might represent, for example, a lock handle that needs to remain active and alive until the block ends:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(a_mutex);
    do_something_on_shared_structure();

    // guard is destructed here.
}
```

`guard` is "no longer used" the moment its construction is complete, but the compiler must emit code that waits until after the call to the following function to destruct the object, or the lock would be released prematurely.

The compiler simply isn't allowed to destruct objects early, because destructors can have side-effects (the release of a lock, in this case).

So the answer in your case is the same: `c` will be destructed immediately before the function returns, which is *after* the call to `magic()`, because the compiler doesn't know what side-effects might happen when `c`'s destructor is invoked.

If you want to destruct `c` early, you can pass the result of `read()` directly into `easy_work()`.  This will result in the construction of a temporary vector as the second argument to `easy_work()`, and it will be destructed immediately after `easy_work()` returns:

```
void foo(std::vector<T>& a, std::string path)
{
    std::vector<P> b = easy_work(a, read(path));

    magic(a, b);
}
```

(Note that you cannot simplify this to `magic(a, easy_work(a, read(path)))` because then the temporary returned by `read()` will continue to exist while `magic()` is called.  The C++ standard says that temporaries exist for as long as the *full-expression* in which they appear, and no longer, and the call to `magic()` would be part of that expression in this case .)

Comment: Great answer. Although I'm still a little surprised the compiler is not allowed to optimise in this way. In your lock example, would it not be clear `a_mutex` is a global variable (or at least not a variable not declared within scope), and is therefore not safe to delete, whereas `c` in my example is declared in scope and is clearly safe to delete?

Comment: @Daniel `a_mutex` is not being destructed, rather it is `guard` that is, which is a local variable. The compiler doesn't pretend to know what these types do. For example, in your case destructing `c` also means destructing every `D` object in the vector -- what if those destructors had side effects and you *wanted* destruction delayed until the end of the function?  What if you were using references to those `D` objects in `magic()` and the compiler destructed them early?

Comment: @Daniel Here is a sample of what I mean: http://pastebin.com/tWrEJiFY -- in this case, if the compiler did destruct `c` early it would destruct all of the `D` objects that you are holding references to through the `P` objects in `b`. The compiler isn't smart enough to figure all of this out, and if `easy_work()` is defined in a different translation unit then the compiler is not even *able* to figure this out since it can't see the function body. The simplest way to avoid this problem is to disallow this kind of optimization. It fails way too easily.

Answer (score 3):

All automatic local variables are destroyed when they go out of scope. `c` will be destroyed automatically when the function returns, after the call to `magic`.